# How to show user friendly error message from Angular default error handler?

Tags: angular

When implementing a default error handler for an angular app I would like to also present the user with a friendly error page. The error handler is implemented following this approach: https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

The only way I could get that to work was to send the user to a different route with code like this:

'`this.router = this.injector.get(Router);
 this.injector.get(NgZone).run(() => this.router.navigate(['/unhandlederror']));`

The downside with this approach is that the user is sent to a different route, hence if they hit F5 to reload - they just reload the error page and not the page that failed on them...

Is it possible to present users with a friendly error message without sending them to a different route using the default error handler?

Comment: You could achieve a similar affect by using observables to send a bool value to a subscriber with the error component

Comment: You can create custom service class and its methods and inside that you can generate the messages.